# how to return item after dynamoDB record update

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am updating a dynamoDB record conditionally (only if the record has a certain value for one of its attributes). I want to get the record back regardless if it was updated successfully (condition was met or not).

```js
docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(
        "Unable to read item. Error JSON:",
        JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)
      );
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    
      

      callback(null, true);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the docs, I figured this out. [AWS DOCS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html), there is a return value attribute that can be set in the params which can take one of the following values: `Valid Values: NONE | ALL_OLD | UPDATED_OLD | ALL_NEW | UPDATED_NEW`.